# Перерисовывать интерфейс в пределах одной формы

Tags: gui, интерфейс, c#

Есть необходимость перерисовывать интерфейс в пределах одной формы. Какие есть варианты по реализации? Создавать элементы интерфейса из кода кажется как то криво. Других вариантов не знаю. Приложение Windows Form.
В C# новичок, так что не закидывайте помидорами.

Comment: Если вы новичок, не начинайте с WinForms. WPF гораздо мощнее, правильнее, проще, и не завязана на окна и WinAPI. В частности, перерисовка в WPF всегда автоматическая, вам никогда не нужно о ней заботиться (как и о других низкоуровневых вещах).

Comment: @VladD а не могли бы Вы подкинуть дельных книг\мануалов по WPF?

Comment: @naym: Ну, например: Adam Nathan. WPF Unleashed (гуглится).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант(пусть и довольно извращенный) — эмуляция фреймов с помощью UserControls.

Создаем базовый UserControl с нужными размерами и другими свойствами, наследуем от него все остальные и заполняем необходимыми компонентами.

Пример реализации [тут](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kqb50o1yfp8eop/WF_Frames.7z)(.NET 4.0, C#, Visual Studio 2010 Project).

Как видим, подобный подход позволяет реализовать наследование фреймов, обеспечить их взаимную независимость(взаимодействие через события) и использовать другие преимущества фреймов.

Но, действительно, лучше смотреть в сторону WPF, как писали в комментах к ответу.